# Cells to columns in OpenRefine

Tags: json, csv, openrefine

I've got a dataset in CSV that I want to convert to JSON. Before conversion, I need to reformat the data to get the proper multidimensional structure. The data contains the results of the last election in Sweden, and it is divided by county ("Kommun"). There are 291 counties, and 9 parties. I want:

- One row per county,
- One column for each party, with each row displaying each party's results.

This would result in 10 columns (county + parties) and 291 rows (1 per county).

How do I achieve this using Open Refine/Google Refine? My current data is shown in the image below.

[image: Open Refine print screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Transpose -> Columnize by key/value` should do the trick.

Comment: I can't really find any good documentation of how that columnization works. What goes into the key column and what goes into the value column? And what column do I transpose?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Using `Transpose -> Columnize by key/value` and selecting the party column as key, and the results column as value actually did the trick. Thanks a ton!